# How do I add the boost library to Xcode 11? C++

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I cannot find a way to add boost in Xcode 11.2.1. I found a setting under the target called "Frameworks and Libraries". I dragged the boost directory there, and it got added to the "Frameworks" section of the project. However, in building the project, it says "file not found". For example:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
```

results in a "file not found" error. Instead of adding boost, I dragged the entire include area of Macports. It took a while for Xcode to parse through that, but I get the same error. So, under Frameworks it has "include", but it cannot find the relevant hpp file, even though I checked and it's there in the boost tree.

I have installed boost via Macports. It resides in /opt/local/include/boost.

In the Xcode documentation, I saw a reference to "USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS". I figured how to set  that in a configuration file, so I added a configuration file to the project. I added this to the configuration file:
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = /opt/local/include/boost
but that does not work either. (If I remove the boost, that does not work either).

When I select "include" in the Frameworks location of the project, I see that there are different settings "Identity and Type" for that object (right side of Xcode window). I selected "absolute path" and it shows the full path as /opt/local/include which is correct. However, this does not solve the problem either.

Do I need to create a link in a pre-defined area so that Xcode can find it?

I did find a rather ugly work-around: create a soft link to the boost library in the same area where the STL resides (within the Xcode.app directory structure).

Using the setting only works with individual files. I can add individual file to the setting (via drag and drop), but it won't follow nested directories, so clearly this will not work for a library implemention such as boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to keep dependent libraries inside project area. So here is how I just do it for test:

1. Create new TestBoost project in Xcode from `macOS Command-line App` C++ template 
   (now there is TestBoost folder where TestBoost.xcodeproj is located)
2. Download latest `boost` [boost_1_72_0.tar.gz](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.72.0/source/boost_1_72_0.tar.gz) and unarchive it 
   (now there `boost_1_72_0` folder with boost)
3. Copy `boost_1_72_0` folder inside project `TestBoost` folder, so it is located aside of TestBoost.xcodeproj
4. In Xcode Project Navigator select `TestBoost` project > select `TestBoost` target > select `Build Settings` tab
5. In `Search Paths` section select `Header Search Path`, double click on value area and enter `${SRCROOT}/boost_1_72_0` (leave `non-recursive` flag)
6. Delete default `main.cpp` from `TestBoost` target (to avoid main function confusing) and add some example from boost for testing, eg. `boost_1_72_0/libs/algorithm/example/search_example.cpp`
7. Build & Run > Success

Output: 
[image: Xcode 11 boost integration]

Comment: Thank you. This works! I wanted to keep boost where it was, so I modified the Header Search path to be /opt/local/include, and boost is in there.

Comment: One problem was that "Search Paths" appears in the Basic options, but it did not show a way to add Header Search Paths until I went to the "All" tab, saw it there, and now, having changed, it appears in Basic options. A little confusing. I checked the docs, and this was not obvious.

Comment: Item 3. Copy boost_1_72_0 folder inside project TestBoost folder, so it is located aside of TestBoost.xcodeproj made it clear to me how to set the search header paths.